# Sed-Script to comment out lines between two multiline markers A\nB and U\nV

Tags: sed

I have the file "test" with the content in (1). I want a sed script, that edits "test" so that i have the output in (2).

I cannot not simply do this:

```
cat test | sed -E '1,/B/!{/U/,$!s/.+/# &/}'
```

...because it would start commenting out beginning from first 'B' and not from 'A\nB'.

(1)

```plaintext
X
X

B

A
B

X
X
X

U

U
V

X
X
```

(2)

```plaintext
X
X

B

A
B

# X
# X
# X

# U

U
V

X
X
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sed is Turing-complete, so you can do anything with it that you can do with any other programming language. Which means that you *can* have a complete solution to the original problem.

In fact, Sed has functions. Functions are just pieces of codes you can jump to and jump back from. The point is knowing where to jump to, forth and back. Setting `:labels`, `b`ranching to them or end of script unconditionally, or jumpting conditionally based on the result of a `t`est is what allows you to write loop and functions in Sed.

Here's a relatively short one-liner accomplishing the original task.

```bash
 sed '/A/{N;s/A\nB/&/;tc};b;:c;n;/U/{N;s/U\nV/&/;t};s/^./\# &/;s/\n/&\# /;bc' file
```

Let me explain using pseudo-code

- `/A/`: if line matches `A`, do `{`

  - `N`: append the next line to the current one`;`
  - `s/A\nB/&/`: check if `A\nB` matches (don't change it, just set the flag for the next `t` command)`;`
  - `t`:est if the flag is set; if so, call the `:c`ommenting function
- `}`: otherwise,
- `b`:ranch to end of script, i.e. print line as is and start over with the next line`;`
- `:c`:ommenting function:

  - `n`, print what you have in pattern space and read the next line
  - `/U/`: if line matches `U`, `{`

    - `N`: append the next line to the current one`;`
    - `s/U\nV/&/`: check if `U\nV` matches (...)`;`
    - `t`: test if the flag is set and; if so, go to end of script, and start over with the next line, going out of the commenting code, `}`
  - `s/^./\# &/` comment non-empty lines
  - `s/\n\(.\)/&\# \1/` also comment non-empty line following a line match `U` in case the former was not a `V`
  - `b`ranch to `:c`ommenting function, i.e. recursive call.

Comment: Fantastic, through branch commands like b,t in combination with substitutions s, which does not change the pattern space and the creative use of n and N, I can solve this task! I am amazed that the hold space is not needed at all. I have removed the `s/\n(.)/&# \1/` command and the script works
nevertheless as desired.

Comment: It happens to work beacuse you've put an empty line after the first `U` line in teh file. And my code was mistaken there. Fixed it now.

Comment: Nice oneliner! Perhaps a slight logic error if the first line of the match(s) were to be doubled up.

Comment: @potong, you're right. Can you check how it looks to you now?

Comment: Nevermind, I broke more than I fixed. I'll revert the change, as it's actually detrimental if the section to be commented are multiple. I'll review it at another time.

Comment: This might work for you `sed 'N;/A\nB/!{P;D};n;:c;N;/U\nV/b;s/^\S/# &/;P;s/.*\n//;tc' file` The idea is to emulate the `D` command between the two markers.

Comment: Ohhhh, I now see the power of the `D` command from the `man` page: _restart cycle with the resultant pattern space, without reading a new line of input_. So it's a bit like being able to undo the `N`. Amazing.

Answer (score 4):

sed is line-oriented, so it's going to be a lot of work to match multi-line markers. You could use `sed -z` to slurp the file into a single "line", but then doing a search-replace on just part of it will be tricky.

perl can handle it:

```bash
perl -0777 -pe 's{(?<=^A\nB$)(.*?)(?=^U\nV$)}
                 {($b = $1) =~ s/^(?=.)/# /gm; $b}gesm' test
```

- `(?<=^A\nB$)(.*?)(?=^U\nV$)` is a regex to match the stuff between the markers,
- then the "inner" s/// command adds the hash at start of lines containing at least 1 character.

Result:

```
X
X

B

A
B

# X
# X
# X

# U

U
V

X
X
```

Comment: Hi glenn, thx for your alternative implemented in in perl.Tested it, works!

I now spent days and hours to learn sed only to find out that sed is the wrong tool for it, damned^^

Comment: @AlexanderSeidl it took me 10 years to learn that :-). In general if you're using sed constructs other than s, g, and p (with -n) then you'd probably be better off using a different tool for some combination of clarity, robustness, and/or portability.

Comment: I would grade the "clarity" of my answer quite poor. Very much of a "quick and dirty one-liner"

Answer (score 1):

sed is a great tool for doing simple substitutions on individual lines but for anything else you'll end up with an indecipherable pile of hieroglyphics that's usually fragile and practically impossible to enhance to do anything different or additional later.

Using GNU awk for multi-char `RS`, `RT` and `gsnsub()`:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { RS="U\nV"; ORS=""; FS=OFS="A\nB" }
    RT && (NF>1) { $NF = gensub(/\n([^\n])/,"\n# \\1","g",$NF) }
    { print $0 RT }
' file
X
X

B

A
B

# X
# X
# X

# U

U
V

X
X
```

The above finds each `U\nV` (RS), splits the text leading up to that into fields on each `A\nB` (FS) if present, then changes every `\nwhatever` into `\n# whatever` in the last such field (`gensub()` on `$NF`) then prints the result. Easy to read/understand (probably after a glance at the man page if you've never seen an awk script before) and trivial to enhance to do anything else you might want to do in future.

Comment: Hi Ed, looks very appealing. But when i apply it to my input file i do not get the desired result. Your command outputs the file without comments and a missing U\nV at the end.

Comment: Ok, now it works, i used the wrong awk. I had to use gawk as you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer by myself. The sed command that does the trick:

```bash
$ cat test | sed -n -E '1h;1!H;${x;s/^(.*?A\nB\n)(.*)(U\nV.*)/\1Marker1\n\2Marker2\n\3/p}' | sed -E '1,/^Marker1/!{/^Marker2/,$!s/.+/# &/}' | sed -E '/^Marker1|Marker2/d'
```

I use sed three times in a pipe to ...

1. read the whole text into the hold space and work on it afterwards
2. insert two textmarker before an after the area, i want to edit
3. comment everything out between the markers
4. delete the markers

And finanally to change the original file, i can do:

```bash
$ cat test | sed -n -E '1h;1!H;${x;s/^(.*?A\nB\n)(.*)(U\nV.*)/\1Marker1\n\2Marker2\n\3/p}' | sed -E '1,/^Marker1/!{/^Marker2/,$!s/.+/# &/}' | sed -E '/^Marker1|Marker2/d' > test.temp;mv test.temp test
```

To make the last operation idempotent, i can use

```bash
$ cat test | sed -n -E '1h;1!H;${x;s/^(.*?A\nB\n)(.*)(U\nV.*)/\1Marker1\n\2Marker2\n\3/p}' | sed -E '1,/^Marker1/!{/^Marker2/,$!s/^[^#]{1}.*/# &/}' | sed -E '/^Marker1|Marker2/d' > test.temp;mv test.temp test;cat test
```

Inspired by the [answer of enlico](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76792563/2725150) and after some digging in the [sed faq](https://github.com/aureliojargas/sed.sf.net/blob/master/local/docs/sedfaq.txt), i found a **super short version** of the solution:

```bash
sed -i -E '$b;/^A$/{$!N;/^A\nB$/{:c;n;/^U$/{$!N;/U\nV$/b};s/^[^#]{1}.*/# &/;bc}}' test
```

And here the expanded version with comments

```
$b                          # if last line end
/^A$/ {                     # if found A
  $!N                       # if it is not last line take next line
  /^A\nB$/ {                # if it is A\nB ...
    :c
    n                       # print and take next line
    /^U$/ {                 # if found B 
     $!N                    # if it is not last line take next line
     /U\nV$/b               # if it is U\nV print and start new cycle
    }
    s/^[^#]{1}.*/# &/       # if line is not empty comment
    bc                      # branch to :c
  }
}
```

Comment: I see you have `.*?` in some of your sed commands - that doesn't mean what you think it does. It means something specific in a PCRE but `sed -E` doesn't uses PCREs, it uses EREs where `.*?` is back-to-back repetition metachars which is undefined behavior.

Comment: @EdMorton, in "man re_format" it says:

"Minimal Repetitions (available for enhanced extended REs only)
By default, the repetition operators, ‘*’, bound, ‘?’ and ‘+’ are greedy; they try to match as many times as possible.  In enhanced mode, appending a ‘?’ to a repetition operator makes it minimal (or ungreedy); it tries to match the fewest number of times (including zero times, as appropriate)."

This is what i wanted to achieve.

Comment: `re_format` is not `sed`. What you quoted about `appending a ‘?’ to a repetition operator makes it minimal (or ungreedy);` is simply wrong for Extended Regular Expressions (as sed -E uses) and I don't know what an `enhanced extended RE` might be (maybe they mean a PCRE?) but whatever it is sed doesn't use them and any repetition metachar (e.g. `*`) followed by another repetition metachar (e.g. `?`) is simply undefined behavior.

Comment: I found a man page for [re_format](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/7/re_format/) and it contains multiple false statements about regexps in general and uses non-standard ambiguous language, IMO you should ignore it and read the man page for the tool you want to use and/or the POSIX spec for that tool and whatever regexp variant(s) it supports to get accurate information.

Comment: @EdMorton, The re_format manual you linked above states in his link that it is osx specific and indeed i found this manual while browsing the manuals on my mac. It has even been linked to from the local sed manual with the statement: "-E ... The re_format(7) manual page fully describes both formats." In my Ubuntu environment sed has a completly different manual for sed. In the Ubuntus sed manual it simply says about the -E option: "-E, -r, --regexp-extended use  extended regular expressions in the script (for portability use POSIX -E)."
Anyway, I believe you and thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;x;/./{x;bb};x;/A\nB/{h;b};:a;P;D;:b;/U\nV/{x;z;x;b};s/^\S/# &/;ba' file
```

Use a flag in the hold space to represent when the current line is between the first and the second markers.

Open a two line buffer.

If the flag in the hold buffer is not set, try to match the first marker and if that is successful, set the flag and break out. Otherwise, print the first line, delete the first line and repeat.

If the flag in the hold buffer is set, try to match the second marker and if that is successful, clear the flag and break out. Otherwise, if the first line is not empty, insert a comment and then print the first line, delete the first line and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

```
 awk -v start="A\nB" \
     -v end="U\nV" \
     -v comment='# ' '
    BEGIN{ 
        split(start, startArray, "\n") 
        split(end, endArray, "\n")
    }
    { a[NR]=$0 }
    END{
        for(i=1; i<=NR; i++){
            if (a[i] == startArray[2] && a[i-1] == startArray[1]){
                print a[i]
                cmt=comment;
                continue    
            }

            if (a[i] == endArray[1] && a[i+1] == endArray[2]) cmt="";
            print (a[i] != "") ? cmt a[i] : a[i]
        }
    }
' file

X
X

B

A
B

# X
# X
# X

# U

U
V

X
X
```